# How to change text settings in a selected item in a FireMonkey TTreeView

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using a TStyleBook to create a custom TTreeView in a simple Windows application. 
I can access the "selection" StyleObject in the TreeViewStyle but I don't know how to change the font color of the selected item (or how to change any TextSettings for that matter). 
Is it possible to choose a style for the text while the item is selected? How can it be done?

Developing in Rad Studio 10.1 Berlin in a Windows 10 environment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was approaching the problem the wrong way.

My solution was to create a TreViewItemStyle and change the properties of its TActiveStyleTextObject (in Delphi Berlin 10.1 a object called "text").

For the especific problem of changing the text color while the item is selected I just changed the ActiveColor property to my desired color.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the text settings when you create the node, but I think you need to reference ResultingTextSettings instead. For instance you could use the following code after you create the node (LNewNode), where SceneTreeView is a FireMonkey TTreeView.

```
LNewNode := TwwSceneTreeNode.Create(SceneTreeView);
LNewNode.Parent:= SceneTreeView; 
LNewNode.Text:= 'Node Text';
LNewNode.ResultingTextSettings.Font.Size:= 8;
LNewNode.ResultingTextSettings.FontColor:= TAlphaColorRec.Red;
```

If you need to change the colors for the selection, you would need to use the tree view's OnChange event, and then set the font color, and clear the previous selection's font.

```
  if SceneTreeView.Selected<>nil then
  begin
     SceneTreeView.Selected.ResultingTextSettings.FontColor:=
          TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
     // Find way to clear earlier font color for 
     // prior selection and put code here
  end;
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not especific enough but what I want is how to settle those settings using my TStyleBook so I don't have to do it mannualy for every item in every tree that I create

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.